# Are the sentences in quotations marks objects of verbs of the main sentences?

Tags: verbs, objects, direct-speech

> Harvold, who has not passed his driving test, said, 'I realized the bus was out of control when I was speaking to the students on the microphone.'

> 'We hit a barrier and swerved to the other side of the road and I grabbed the wheel,' Harvold explained.

Are those quotations objects of the verbs say and explain?

Answer (score 1):

> [1] *Harvold, who has not passed his driving test, said, "I realized the*
> *bus was out of control when I was speaking to the students on the*
> microphone".
>
> [2] "*We hit a barrier and swerved to the other side of the road and I*
> *grabbed the wheel", Harvold explained.*

No: direct reported speech does not function as an object.

In [1] the direct speech is embedded as the **complement** of the reporting verb "say".

In [2] it is non-embedded, functioning as a **main clause**. The reporting frame "Harvold explained" has the status of a parenthetical.

Comment: Thank you for adding to this post. In [1] it's a complex sentence, a dependent clause embedded in a main clause, which has a direct speech as complement of its verb. Do we also have a complex sentence in [2], with the parenthetical addition being a dependent clause?

Comment: @mjfneto [1] is not a complex sentence. In the case of direct reported speech, as in your examples, the reported speech (a complement) in [1] is not actually a subordinate clause. The construction involves the embedding of a **text**, not a clause as such, and the sentence is thus a simple one. The same applies in [2], where we have a simple clause with a parenthetical rather than an embedded subordinate clause as such.

Comment: In [1], isn't the clause between commas a dependent clause? It's nonessential but dependent nonetheless, isn't it?

Comment: @mjfneto Yes, I overlooked the fact that there is a subordinate relative clause, thus it's a complex sentence. My apologies.

Comment: It's completely fine! My "embedded" qualifying "dependent clause" might have been the source of confusion.

Comment: Could you possibly share a reference which confirms what you have pointed out about direct reported speeches not functioning as objects?